# Where I can see my IDFV on iPhone?

Tags: ios

As IDFA is being removed I want to make test using IDFV. Where I can see it on my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it programmatically:

```
let uuid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor?.uuidString
```

Actually your question is not totally right...

> As IDFA is being removed I want to make test using IDFV

IDFA hasn't been removed. We can say they depowered IDFA requiring a scary permission to the user. In practice the IDFA is still there but it's almost unusable. IDFV is not a real replacement because it doesn't identify reliably a single device. As stated in the doc:

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them.

Also, when you say...

> Where I can see it on my iPhone?

I think it's accessible only programmatically. You can't see IDFV in a settings page, also because your device have many IDFVs, it's not unique. Every app as a different IDFV, unless you have more apps of the same vendor, in that case they will have the same IDFV.

IDFV: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor

IDFA: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/adsupport/asidentifiermanager/1614151-advertisingidentifier